# MAPS software on colocated server

Tags: colocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

As a participant in MAPS program, are we allowed to place the software installation on a colocated server , or does it have to be installed in the office itself ?

Also, is this scenario viable: 
Usimg MAPS windows as a OS, are we allowed to allow our own software to be publicly reachable ? 
( we have a MAPS Windows driven server , and we would like to present software we made, and is installed on it to our customers as trial, to reach the software, Client would have to connect to windows by RDP)

Comment: A) MAPS? B) Isn't this a question for you to ask the people you licensed it from?

Answer (score 1):

This question is best answered with the answer "Ask Microsoft", but I'll throw a few things out:

1. I'm assuming you have a Microsoft Action Pack Development and Design subscription.
2. I'll assume you haven't read this page:

https://mspartner.microsoft.com/en/us/pages/membership/action-pack-dev-design-software-contents.aspx

Which clearly states "Software licenses for Microsoft Action Pack Development and Design are for use at your company’s primary business location only. They must be used only for: Managing internal business. Conducting demos with your customers. Training your employees. Developing and testing applications. These licenses may not be used for direct revenue-generating activities (such as website or email hosting, or custom solution development for monetary compensation). They also cannot be resold or used for personal reasons."

So if you're presenting your software (and the undelying platform) to your customers for the purpose of demo'ing your software then you're probably OK, but I would strongly suggest contacting MAPS support and asking them directly.